# Automatically populate DateTime field with last week's date using an extension method

Tags: c#

I have two DateTime fields that I'd like to automatically fill so that the PeriodFrom field is set to 7 days ago and the PeriodTo field is set to today's date.

At present I have them set up so that the PeriodFrom is set to the first day of the month with the following code:

```
  PeriodFrom = DateTime.Now.FirstDayOfMonth();
  PeriodTo = DateTime.Today;
```

where FirstDayOfMonth() is the extension method:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(this DateTime dateTime)
{
  return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
}
```

Is there a quick extension method that I could write to set the date to exactly 1 week ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static DateTime OneWeekAgo(this DateTime dateTime)
{
  return dateTime.AddDays(-7);
}
```

Usage, as you already understand, like this:

```
PeriodFrom = DateTime.Now.OneWeekAgo();
PeriodTo = DateTime.Today;
```